# SQL Server trigger to concatenate strings and append additional text

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-concatenation, concatenation

I have 2 tables in MS SQL Server 2008:

Table: ADOMAccounts

```
AccountID   ADOMName     ADOMPermission
1000        Company_A    Read_Only
1000        Company_A    Read_Write
1001        Company_B    Read_Only
1001        Company_B    Read_Write
```

Table: SUBSCRIBERS  (ADOMPermission is inserted separately per user)

```
USERNAME    REPLYATTR           AccountID    ADOMPermission
alice       NULL                1000         Read_Only
bob         NULL                1001         Read_Write
```

We currently have a trigger on inserts to SUBSCRIBERS to update the REPLYATTR value for 'bob' with:

```
Name="Company_B",Profile="Read_Write",Service-Type="Login-User"
```

Trigger: tr_GenerateReplyAttr

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_GenerateReplyAttr ON SUBSCRIBERS
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE Existing
SET Replyattr = 'Name="' + Accounts.ADOMName +
                    '",Profile="' + New.ADOMPermission +
                    '",Service-Type="Login-User"'

FROM Subscribers AS Existing
    INNER JOIN inserted AS New ON New.Username = Existing.Username
    INNER JOIN ADOMAccounts AS Accounts 
        ON New.AccountID = Accounts.AccountID AND New.ADOMPermission = Accounts.ADOMPermission
WHERE New.AccountID != '' AND New.ADOMPermission != ''

RETURN
```

But we now have a need that if ADOMAccounts contained Company_C with the same AccountID as Company_B, that the REPLYATTR for 'bob' would look like this:

```
Name="Company_B",Name="Company_C",Profile="Read_Only",Service-Type="Login-User"
```

So basically matching on AccountID and concatenating distinct ADOMName's with prepended text, appended by text and values.  There shouldn't be too many ADOMName's on the same AccountID (2-3 maybe), but could possibly be more.

I've been looking through other articles on concatenating strings, but fell down on making them distinct and appending the additional text and values.

Comment: Are you sure you need to store these convoluted, formatted, arrangements of *existing* data in the database? Would these not be better formatted in a front-end of some sort (or, if you do want to do it in the database for consistency, just doing it during `SELECT`). Why does this string have to be *stored*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever We have a Radiator radius server which queries the database for the REPLYATTR, the text of which is Vendor Specific Attributes (VSAs).  In the radius config we use AuthSelect and a select query after it, but I'm not sure what the length limits are on this query.  I'm open to suggestions on doing this in a select query on the radius server, and can test out it's limits.

Answer (score 1):

Update your trigger code with this code.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_GenerateReplyAttr] ON [dbo].[SUBSCRIBERS]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE Existing
SET Replyattr = (Select 'Name="' + ADOMName 
                From ADOMAccounts A 
                Where A.AccountID = New.AccountID And New.ADOMPermission =             A.ADOMPermission For XML PATH ('')) +
                '",Profile="' + New.ADOMPermission +
                '",Service-Type="Login-User"'

FROM Subscribers AS Existing
    INNER JOIN inserted AS New ON New.Username = Existing.Username
WHERE New.AccountID != '' AND New.ADOMPermission != ''

GO
```

now insert new record as you want and check your data.

Answer (score 0):

We've had to do something similar; give this a try:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_GenerateReplyAttr] ON [dbo].[SUBSCRIBERS]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
UPDATE Existing
SET [REPLYATTR] = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '",Name="' + ADOMName
                         FROM ADOMAccounts
                         WHERE ADOMAccounts.AccountID = New.AccountID
                         AND New.ADOMPermission = ADOMAccounts.ADOMPermission
                     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') +
                '",Profile="' + New.ADOMPermission +
                '",Service-Type="Login-User"'

FROM Subscribers AS Existing
    INNER JOIN inserted AS New ON New.Username = Existing.Username
WHERE New.AccountID != '' AND New.ADOMPermission != ''
```